# Python Split a phrase into words on space and symbols

Tags: python, string, split

I'm writing a program where I need to test whether a phrase such as "red car" is present in a variety of sentences: "I bought a new red car", "RED! CAR!", "red#$%^car".

I'm having trouble finding a way to separate out the words from the symbols in the last example.

My code so far is:

```
exclude = set(string.punctuation)

text = text.lower
text = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
text = text.split()

for word in phrase:
    found = False
    for e2 in text:
        if word == e2:
           found = True
           break
    if not found:
       return False
return True
```

This causes the last example to be 'redcar' so the words aren't split.

All the questions I found on here were talking about delimiters not splitting out two words that are joined by a bunch of symbols.

Should I just use text.split for each individual symbol?

I was thinking of something like:

```
for ch in exclude:
    text = text.split(ch)
```

but I was hoping there is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is pretty much tailor made for a regular expression, such as:

```
import re
red_car = re.compile(r"\bred\W{1,5}car\b", re.I)

if red_car.search("I bought a red#$%^car yesterday"):
    print("found a red car")
```

The important components of the regular expression are:

```
\b     matches a word boundary at start and end so as not to match "tired carrot"
\W     matches any non-word character between "red" and "car"
{1,5}  matches from one to five occurrences of \W between "red" and "car"
re.I   makes the regex ignore case (match "RED car" etc.)
```

Comment: Curses, you beat me to it. I would recommend using `r'red.*car'` for the pattern, so you match any number of arbitrary characters between "red" and "car". I suppose `r'red\W*car'` might be better if we know that we will only have non-alphanumeric characters between our words.

Comment: My thinking was that `red car` with alphabetic letters between `red` and `car` no longer said `red car`.  :-)  Similarly, at some point, with too many non-word characters in between, it is no longer `red car`.Using `{1,5}` makes it easy to fine-tune it as needed.

Comment: @kindall This works perfectly! Thank you. One followup question: Suppose I wouldn't know ahead of time what the phrase would be. Is there a way to sub-in parts of the phrase? Like: phrase_re = re.compile(r"\b{0}\W{1,6}{1}\b".format(phrase2[0],phrase2[1])) ? I tried this but got a KeyError: '1,6'

Comment: The reason you're getting a `KeyError` is that `.format()` is trying to substitute into the `{1,5}` part of the regular expression. You could write that as `{{1,5}}` so `.format()` leaves it alone. Or you could use the `%` operator (or even good old-fashioned string concatenation) to avoid this problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the sentences and see if both `red` and `car` exist in the sentences:

```
sentences = ["I bought a new red car", "RED! CAR!", "red#$%^car"]
final_sentences = [sentence for sentence in sentences if "red" in sentence.lower() and "car" in sentence.lower()]
```